# Random absorption hearts when creeper exploded

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was surrounded by mobs.

I had eaten a dandelion suspicious stew 10 minutes earlier, in case that matters.

I got 2 absorption hearts when a creeper exploded.

Is this a glitch or is this intended

I was playing minecraft BE in the latest version, 1.16.201

Comment: Do you have a totem of undying?

Comment: No I have not started a raid or raided a woodland mansion in that world.

Comment: DO you have any effects at that time from the stew

Comment: This could be a bug that can't be reproduced, mainly because suspicious stews are quite random, and speaking of your Absorption, how many hearts did you have when the creeper exploded (apart from the golden ones)?

Comment: I had 4 hearts and took half a heart of damage from the explosion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that it’s a bug... I haven’t heard of this happening. Maybe try to reproduce the circumstances and see if the same thing happens? That could tell you whether or not it is a one time thing. Hope this helps!

Comment: That would involve more suspicous stew and drinking 2 harming potions. Harming potions are expensive and I do not want to waste those which I could be using on enemies.

Comment: @Abraham Certain mobs can heal with splash potions of harming, like zombies and its similar types.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe the group is undead

Comment: @Abraham do it in a cheats enabled world